# Do I need an async function to properly include a working preloader component?

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, state, preloader

I'm working with an Electron React app, and I'm curious if I need an asynchronous function to properly display a preloader svg. The svg is stored in state, and when I test it out by showing it and not removing it, it works perfectly fine. However, when I actually try to use it in the process of my app, it never seems to show up.

[Here's what I'd like it to look like](https://gyazo.com/3015c7e03f10cc516d0e9896556609f4) (I achieve this by commenting out where I change the state back to null after processing files)

[Here's what I get instead](https://gyazo.com/d8e051b54c75f90604fc6dd1528ecfa4) (What happens when I change the state from the loader back to null... there's no loader in sight!)

My question is, is this something I need an async function to achieve? I'm not extremely familiar with properly using async await, and this isn't the first time I've run into this issue in a react app. I'm just generally trying to figure out why the loader never seems to appear when I implement it as intended. I honestly may just be making a newbie error here, so I'd like a second opinion!

in App.js:

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(null);

const handleLoading = (value) => {
    setLoading(value);
};

...

<Route exact path="/list">
    <List loading={loading} />
</Route>
<Route exact path="/">
    <Start loading={handleLoading} />
</Route>
```

in Start.js

```
const handleFiles = (files) => {
            // *set the loading state to the component
            props.loading(
                <div className="base-loader">
                    <div className="preloader-wrapper big active">
                        <div className="spinner-layer spinner-blue-only">
                            <div className="circle-clipper left">
                                <div className="circle"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="gap-patch">
                                <div className="circle"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="circle-clipper right">
                                <div className="circle"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
            // counter to list with a Materialize toast when finished if > 0
            sendFiles(files);
            if (incompatibleFiles > 0) {
                M.toast({
                    html: `${incompatibleFiles} file(s) could not be minified due to incompatible file type.`,
                });
            }
            // reset for next drag and drop
            incompatibleFiles = 0;

            // *THIS is the line I comment out for it to start working (although it just goes infinitely)
            props.loading(null);
        };
```

And lastly in List.js, I simply just include `{props.loading}` in the component return statement.

Comment: Have you tried adding a delay to the commented out line with `setTimeout` just to see if the loader shows up? Sometimes the loading is instant and the loader just doesn't have time to show.

Comment: Also, recommend to use a boolean value for the loading state instead of `null`.

Comment: Using setTimeout worked like a charm! Thank you so much, I'll make sure to utilize that in the future!

Comment: Do you mind accepting my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is likely because the loading is instant and the loader doesn't appear long enough to notice. If you try setting a timeout before setting the `loading` state to `false` the loader should be noticeable:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  setLoading(false);
}, 500);
```

However, I think it is not necessary to fake the loading behavior if it happens quick enough. The best practice is probably to start showing a loader after 500ms-1000ms or something when the average human user starts to feel that your application isn't responsive if there is no change.

```
let timeout = setTimeout(() => {
  if (!dataHasLoaded) {
    setLoading(true);
  } else {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
  }
}, 500);
```